# Randomly select an element from a list, but the lower an element is, the more chance it has to be selected

Tags: python-3.x, random

I want to randomly select an item from a list. But the twist is that the higher index an element in the list possesses, the most likely it will be chosen. And after randomly choosing an item in the list, I would like to store that item into a variable named `link`.

I haven't tried a lot of different ways, since I don't know where to start. But this is what I currently have:

```
import random

# A list of Youtube links ( I won't show the YT links )
links = ['link1 :D',
         'link2 :D',
         'link3 :D'
]

link = random.choice(links)
```

With the code above, I only get a random ( or pseudorandom ) result from an item in the `links` variable. How can I write the code so that it has a higher of choosing ( but still randomly ) the items with a larger index?

## In case I'm not being clear, here is an example:

```
# List of 3 links

links = ['link1', # index: 0
'link2', # index: 1
'link3' # index: 2]
```

Since `link3` has the highest index of 2, it has the highest possibility of being selected by a random selector. `link2` has the second-highest index, so it has more chances of being selected than `link1`, but fewer chances of being selected than `link3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New in **Python 3.6**. For the previous Python version [see here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#examples-and-recipes).

You can use the `weights` or `cum_weights` parameter in [**`random.choices()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) to select according to the relative weights.

Since you want a higher change of selection for elements present at higher index, you can make your weights index based.

```
weights = [i for i in range(1, len(links) + 1)]
```

Internally, the relative weights(`weights`) are converted to cumulative weights(`cum_weights`) before making selections.

```
random.choices(links, weights=weights)
```

**Note:** If a `weights` sequence is supplied, it must be of the same length as the sample sequence.